# Populating a tableview in xcode with objects from an array is causing an out of bounds exception

Tags: xcode, tableview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am parsing some data from an online feed and then putting that data into multiple objects, I then have a page that display options which then goes onto a tableview that shows all parts within that array.

The problem that I am coming up with is that 10/11 options work with no problems, the final option that I have comes up with an out of bounds exception if you have viewed another option and then tried to enter it. If that 11th option is entered first then it works fine, if you view other options then close the option page and go back into it to view the 11th option it also works fine.

This is the code that I have that sorts out the data into areas (this bit is just the part that I am having problems with):

```
-(void)TBSortOut {
    [app.TBArray removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"this is running");
      for (int i = 200; i < app.listArray.count; i++) {
          theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:i];
          if ([theList.course rangeOfString:@"Time Based Art & Digital Film" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
          }else{
            [self sortOutArray];
            [app.TBArray addObject:theList];
            theList = nil;
          }
       }
}
```

Followed by the section of code that is within my masterViewController that sorts out the cells within the table, and where I believe that my problem is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
@try{
  theList = NULL;
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
   }
   //selecting which array to display within the tableview
   if (app.courseChoice == 11) {
     theList = [app.TBArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 1) {
     theList = [app.AniArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 2) {
     theList = [app.APCPArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 3) {
     theList = [app.DIXDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 4) {
     theList = [app.FAArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 5) {
     theList = [app.GDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 6) {
     theList = [app.ILLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 7) {
     theList = [app.IEDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice ==  {
     theList = [app.JEWArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 9) {
     theList = [app.PROArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else if (app.courseChoice == 10) {
     theList = [app.TEXArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } 

   //sets name of the cell and the type of indicator used within the cell(arrow)
   cell.textLabel.text = theList.fullname;
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

   return cell;
 }
 @catch(NSException *e){
   NSLog(@"catching %@ reason %@", [e name], [e reason]);
 }
}
```

The error that the try catch is printing is:

```
catching NSRangeException reason *** - [_NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]
```

I have tried printing out at various points within the code with `NSLog` and what appears to happen is that the table tries to load the information before the previous view has told the table which view to use, therefore the tableview tries to load the table with a larger array and runs into an error when it realises that the array it is loading is smaller than the one it thinks it should be.

**How do I solve this?** Is there some way that I can put the code within the `try`/`catch` inside an `if` that stops it running if it has reached the end of the selected array? Or is there some way that I can force the app to reload the page with options so that the problems stops?

EDIT: Logs prior to crash, first set are from the option page before displaying in a tableview, shows counts for each separate array. Second set show the arrays once one has been chosen and the course coice just as the app crashes(the '(m)' is simply so that I know the logs are coming from different views):

```
2013-04-30 15:23:14.985 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] AniArray amount 17
2013-04-30 15:23:14.986 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] APCPArray amount 6
2013-04-30 15:23:14.987 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] DIXDArray amount 5
2013-04-30 15:23:14.987 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] FAArray amount 65
2013-04-30 15:23:14.988 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] GDArray amount 17
2013-04-30 15:23:14.989 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] ILLArray amount 19
2013-04-30 15:23:14.990 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] IEDArray amount 23
2013-04-30 15:23:14.990 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] JEWArray amount 20
2013-04-30 15:23:14.991 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] PROArray amount 26
2013-04-30 15:23:14.992 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] TEXArray amount 26
2013-04-30 15:23:14.992 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] TBArray amount 10

2013-04-30 15:24:31.819 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)AniArray amount 17
2013-04-30 15:24:31.820 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)APCPArray amount 6
2013-04-30 15:24:31.820 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)DIXDArray amount 5
2013-04-30 15:24:31.821 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)FAArray amount 65
2013-04-30 15:24:31.821 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)GDArray amount 17
2013-04-30 15:24:31.822 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)ILLArray amount 19
2013-04-30 15:24:31.823 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)IEDArray amount 23
2013-04-30 15:24:31.823 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)JEWArray amount 20
2013-04-30 15:24:31.824 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)PROArray amount 26
2013-04-30 15:24:31.824 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)TEXArray amount 26
2013-04-30 15:24:31.825 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)TBArray amount 10
2013-04-30 15:24:31.829 Degree Show 2013[5665:907] (m)course choice = 11
```

EDIT 2: 
Some developments, I have added a `@finally` after the `try/catch` and that is stopping the crash but causing some extra cells to appear in the final view, the number actually seems to be the number of objects within the previous array that you visit.
Also should mention that all this testing has been done on an iPhone 5, I have just tried it on an iPhone 4, and it all works perfectly. Are tables handled different by the newer iphones than the previous ones?

Comment: what happens when you log the count of each array before the if-else statement? You've only showed the initialisation of one array (and the for loop starting at 200 seems wrong to me but I'm not sure of the array its based on)

Comment: When checked they all return the numbers that are meant to be in each separate array, all of them are sorted out in a similar function to the one shown above. That one starts at 200 because none of the data for that array is present before object 200, it was initially starting at 0 though I changed it to see if it would make a difference, which it doesn't.

Comment: can you show the logs (and log which array is being counted at each time), and log what app.courseChoice and indexPath.row. (so we can see what the state was just before the crash)

Comment: I have added the codes to the original question in an edit and have also posted some strange developments that I have found, hope it helps

Comment: Okay, just to let you know, I rebuilt the page because the version was working for iPhone 4, and that seems to have fixed all the problems that it was causing. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your are going to be able to really solve this issue with the code that you currently have.  My best guess is that you are changing the data the tableView is displaying is changing between the datasource and delegate calls.

What I'd do is create a single array that the tableView displays from, instead of doing the giant if/else block.  And in the code that sets the app.courseChoice value set the new tableView data array to the proper array and then tell the tableView to reload.

Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)changeCourseChoice:(id)sender
{
    app.courseChoice = [sender selectedIndex];
    if (app.courseChoice == 11) {
      self.theList = [app.TBArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (app.courseChoice == 1) {
      self.theList = [app.AniArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } // ...

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```